# Vim-Latex and subfiles without breaking autocompletion

Tags: cross-referencing, subfiles, vim-latex

I am using `vim-latex` to compile my latex code, but I want to use the latex package `subfiles`.

My structure is this:

```
├── main.tex    
├── main.tex.latexmain
└── part
    ├── part.tex
    └── part.tex.latexmain
```

And the file contents are

```
main.tex:

\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\label{abc}
\subfile{./part/part.tex}
\end{document}
```

and

```
part.tex:
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
text: \ref{abc}
\end{document}
```

So, I have 2 latexmain files there.

1. I want to edit and then compile `part.tex` and let the `subfiles` package do its work
2. I want `vim-latex` to recognize `main.tex` a the master file so it can autocomplete references.

Can this be done somehow? Or is there a better way to efficiently work with large projects in `vim-latex`? With efficiently I mean that you can only compile the part of the document you are working on.

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Regarding ways to structure the document: My first suggestion usually is to split the document into several files and include them into the main file using `\input`. The main file is then just a list of `\input` statements, and you can easily comment out those parts that you do not want to compile at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That is what I ended up doing, plus, using the `vim-latex` "Compile parts of a file" (http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/part-compiling.html). I am still wondering, though, what the advantage of `subfiles` would've been. I can't see the advantage of using the package

Comment: Sometimes people want to be able to compile documents separately, keeping them in different directories, with the path to local images and other auxiliary files relative to these documents, but they also want to compile the documents as part of a single document. With simple \inputs this wouldn't work, as the path information has to be relative to the main document. But I fully agree that for most applications one can do without the `subfiles` package. See also the introduction of the [subfiles docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf) that motivates the package

Comment: *"The subfiles package allows authors to split a document into one main
file and several subsidiary files (subfiles) akin to the \input command, with
the added benefit of making the subfiles compilable on their own. This is
achieved by reusing the preamble of the main file also for the subfiles."* [[subfiles docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf), Abstract]

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. `vim-latex`'s option to compile a part of the document is also copying the preamble. What I am doing to avoid the path-dependence is setting the `\graphicspath{}` for each `\input`. I do not have nested `\inputs`